# Automated employee scheduling and resource allocation application

Tags: scheduling, resource-management

My company is an event management company and we have 25 employees. We organize and setup events for our clients. Currently, scheduling is done manually using Excel and it is very tedious to keep track and ensure that the resources are properly allocated.

So, I'm trying to find the right software to automate this scheduling process but I've no luck so far.

These are the employee constraints that the software must be able to handle:

1. Each event is handled by 1 team and each team has a minimum of 2 employees.
2. Each team can handle 2 events per day.
3. Only 10 employees have a fixed role that are crucial for an event (let's call them Controllers). So for each event, there must be at least 1 Controller.
4. All controllers have a fixed rank from 1-10 (1 is highest ranked, 10 is lowest ranked). The higher they are ranked, the more events they have to handle.

These are the equipment constraints that must be handled:

1. Each team are allocated a fixed item of 1 item A, 1 item B, and 1 item C.
2. Depending on the event configurations and client requests, other items (item D, E, F, G, etc...) can be increased.
3. There is a limit on each number of other items (item D, E, F, G, etc...). So for example, if an event requires all of item G, other events that also require item G have to be rejected or requested to move to other days. Of course, all this is pre-planned on a first-come-first-serve basis.

These are my software requirements:

1. Support Windows 10 Pro or Google Chrome
2. Able to export to Excel or CSV file
3. Paid or non-paid

Answer (score -1):

Gantt chart is the best management tool you should look for while dealing with resources, timeline, and events.
The resource allocation view in Gantt chart helps you to display the events assigned for each resource individually along the timeline.

[The Syncfusion Gantt chart](https://www.syncfusion.com/jquery/javascript-ui-controls/gantt-chart) allows you to view the events assigned for each resource in your organization on the fly with its rich set of features.

The [resource allocation view](https://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/bootstrap/gantt/ResourceView) in Gantt chart also helps you to check which resource is over-allocated with events and which resource is available on a given timeline.
And you can add or remove an event from the timeline using the add and edit toolbar options available in the Gantt chart.

You can find an example below with resource allocation view in Gantt chart which may satisfy your requirement.

https://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/5ymgtgye

Regards,

Bharath.

Comment: Hi, thanks for contributing but what I'm really looking for is something that can **automatically** generate the schedule and assign resources based on the constraints I have. I can't see anything in this gantt chart that does that.